# Is it possible to "forward" the positional type arguments of 1 type to another?

Tags: typescript, react-query

I am using `react-query`, and which provides this function which has 4 type arguments:

```
useMutation<TData = unknown, TError = unknown, TVariables = void, TContext = unknown>
```

I created a object with type information like this:

```
const options: MutationObserverOptions<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD> = {
  mutationFn: someFn,
  onMutate: async (variables) => {},
  onSuccess: (result, variables, context) => {},
  onError: (error, variables, context) => {},
  retry: 3,
};
```

You can assume TypeA, TypeB, TypeC and TypeD have been defined elsewhere.

From this `options` variable with type `MutationObserverOptions<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD>` I want to extract the positional type arguments `TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD` and forward them to `useMutation`.

```
const mutation = useMutation<typeof mutationOptions>('myMutationKey');
```

The code above is wrong, because it is uses the whole type.
I tried using `Parameters<typeof mutationOptions>` but that doesn't work because `mutationOptions` is not a function.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: This isn't possible yet.

Comment: You'd need higher-kinded types to do this generically, but as a workaround you can infer a tuple with the four parameter types and index that to get the `useMutation` type parameters: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WY3ZxN)